# Microsoft software installer fails

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install an application on my computer and anytime I get an error which states

> system error &H80004023(-2147467229) Microsoft software installer error was encountered

Does any one know how this can be fixed?
I am using windows 7 professional

Comment: Is it just this one application that fails or do others fail as well? What application is it? Where did you get it from?

Comment: "Microsoft software installer"? Never heard of it. " &H80004023"? That's not a Microsoft error code either. I smell malware.

Comment: others can get installed easily but this one no. This is a program application for an oscilloscope

Comment: @FleetCommand if you take out the "&H" and search for just the number it appears to be a Microsoft Office automation error. Could be whatever is being installed expects Office or some other COM accessible application.

Comment: @ShirinMalekjani Telling us what actual software it is and where to get it from (legitimately) is going to help people to solve your problem. Many PC oscilloscope companies provide their software for free as it's the hardware that has the cost attached to it. Hiding details prevents us from helping you.

Comment: http://www.fastsampling.com/PHP/downloads.php. this is the website from which I downloaded my program. The last two ones the required one for my oscilloscope DS800

Comment: system error &H80004023 looks like it came from a visual basic application.  I would be suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service itself is correctly started (It's called Windows Installer under services).

Then, what can be tried 1st is to re-register it:

Click Start, Run and type **MSIEXEC /UNREGISTE**R, and then click OK. Even if you
do this correctly, it may look like nothing occurs. Then Click Start, Run and type **MSIEXEC /REGSERVER**, and then click OK. Even if you do this correctly, it may look like nothing occurs. Not a problem; try your Windows installer-based program again.

If that does not fix it, run a **sfc /scannow** for integrity check.

If that didn't work, some related reg fixes can be found [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/misc-registry-fixes-for-windows-10-7-8-xp-vista/)

Comment: Installer 5.0 is already builtin to Windows 7, so you can't install 4.5

Comment: Indeed, it seems W7SP1 has already updated to v5. I have updated the answer with other possible solutions.